# Will Windows Server 2008 R2 software RAID volume with “Failed Redundancy” be available during resynching?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid, raid1

In addition to this question: [Windows Server software RAID volume constant "Failed Redundancy"](https://serverfault.com/questions/80344/windows-server-software-raid-volume-constant-failed-redundancy)

I have this problem on my production server too, but im concerned about resynching. 
If I start resynching, will the volume be available to use or system will have to unmount it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the volume doesn't need to be unmounted.

Yes, the volume will be available during the resync.

RAID would be somewhat pointless if you needed to unmount a volume in order to resync data after a failed drive replacement.

Comment: Glad to help...